# Nativescript listview not updating on a particular view

Tags: listview, mobile, typescript, angular, nativescript

I'm working on an app to display a list of issues related to a project. The app flow is explained as follows:

1. The user logs into the app.
2. A list view with list of projects being listed(working fine).
3. On clicking the project cell, issues related to corresponding projects are loaded.(Not working even though the issues are displayed on log).

Both the projects and issues are listed in the same way and I can't find what's wrong with issues view as I get a blank screen instead of the list view.

When I call the issue service API from projects component by commenting the projects services API, I get the projects list view updated with the issues list. The issue services are exact replica of the project view implementation files but still it doesn't seem to work out. Attaching the codes for both the views.

**Projects View**

1. projects.html

```html
 <GridLayout> 
       <ListView [items]="projects" class="small-spacing"        (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
           <template let-item="item">
              <Label [text]="item.projectName" class="medium-spacing">      </Label>
           </template>
       </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

2. projects-list.service.ts

   ```
   import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
   import {Projects} from "./projects";
   import {ApiBase} from "../../shared/apiBase/apibase";
   import {Config} from "../utils/config"
   import {User} from "../user/user";

   var applicationSettings = require("application-settings");

   @Injectable()
   export class ProjectsService extends ApiBase {
    apiBase : ApiBase;

    loadProjects(callBack: (responseObject:any, authDetails: String)=>any) {

        var url =Config.BASE_URL + "/projects.json";
       console.log("URL -" + url);
       console.log("Auth -" + Config.AUTH_DATA_KEY);
       this.getRequest(Config.AUTH_DATA_KEY, url, callBack);
   ```

   }

   ```
   fetchIssues(callBack: (responseObject:any, authDetails: String)=>any) {

        var url =Config.BASE_URL + "/issues.json?project_id=215" ;
       console.log("URL -" + url);
       console.log("Auth -" + Config.AUTH_DATA_KEY);
       this.getRequest(Config.AUTH_DATA_KEY, url, callBack);
   ```

   }
   }
3. projects.component.ts

   ```
   import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
   import observable = require("data/observable");
   import {Projects} from "../../shared/projects/projects";
   import {ProjectsService} from "../../shared/projects/projects-list.service";
   import {Router} from "@angular/router-deprecated";

   var EventBus = require('eventbusjs');
   @Component({
     selector: "projects",
     providers: [ProjectsService],
     templateUrl: "views/projects/projects.html",
     styleUrls: ["views/projects/projects.css"],
   })
   export class ProjectsPage implements OnInit {
     projects = [];
     constructor(private _projectsService: ProjectsService, private _router: Router) {}

   ngOnInit() {
    let projectsList = this.projects;
    var callback = function callback(response) {

     JSON.parse(response.content).projects.forEach(project => {
       projectsList.push(new Projects(project.id, project.name));
       console.log("project.name - " + project.name);
     })
   }
      this._projectsService.loadProjects(callback);


    }
     public onItemTap(args) {
       console.log("------------------------ ItemTapped: " + this.projects[args.index].id);
       this._router.navigate(["IssuesList", {projectID : this.projects[args.index].id}]);
    }
   }
   ```

The files related to the issue view are also similar. But I'm unable to figure out what's wrong with the issues view as the list view is not being shown. The files related to issues view are following.

1. issues.html

```html
<GridLayout>
  <ListView [items]="issues" class="small-spacing" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
    <template let-issue="issue">
      <Label [text]="issue.issueSubject" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
    </template>
  </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

1. isseus-list.service.ts

   ```
   import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
   import {Issues} from "./issues";
   import {ApiBase} from "../../shared/apiBase/apibase";
   import {Config} from "../utils/config"

   var applicationSettings = require("application-settings");

   @Injectable()
   export class IssuesService extends ApiBase {
     apiBase : ApiBase;

     fetchIssues(callBack: (responseObject:any, authDetails: String)=>any) { 
        var url =Config.BASE_URL + "/issues.json?project_id=215" ;
       console.log("URL -" + url);
       console.log("Auth -" + Config.AUTH_DATA_KEY);
       this.getRequest(Config.AUTH_DATA_KEY, url, callBack);
     }
   }
   ```
2. issues.component.ts

   ```
   import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
   import observable = require("data/observable");
   import {Issues} from "../../shared/issues/issues";
   import {IssuesService} from "../../shared/issues/issues-list.service";
   import {Router} from "@angular/router-deprecated";

   var EventBus = require('eventbusjs');
   @Component({
     selector: "issues",
     providers: [IssuesService],
     templateUrl: "views/issues/issues.html",
     styleUrls: ["views/issues/issues.css"],
   })
   export class IssuesPage implements OnInit{
     issues = [];
     constructor(private _issuesService: IssuesService, private _router: Router) {}

   ngOnInit() {
       let issuesList = this.issues;
       var i = 0;
       var callback = function callback(response) {

         JSON.parse(response.content).issues.forEach(issue => {
        issuesList.push(new Issues(issue.id, issue.status.name, issue.tracker.name, issue.tracker.name));
       console.log("issue.name - " + issuesList[i].projectName);
       i++;
         })
       }
       this._issuesService.fetchIssues(callback);
     }
      public onItemTap(args) {
           console.log("------------------------ ItemTapped: " + this.issues[args.index].id);
       //this._router.navigate(["IssuesList", {projectID : this.issues[args.index].id}]);
       }
   }
   ```

The console.log() in issues.compnent.ts returns the data while the list view is blank as given in the above screenshot. Can anyone help me get through this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your `issues.html`?

Comment: The issues.html file is there in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ngOnInit` you do not assign to `this.issues` the new values

So make sure you do in your `callback` function

```
...
issues = [];
var self = this;
...

   var callback = function callback(response) {

      JSON.parse(response.content).issues.forEach(issue => {
     issuesList.push(new Issues(issue.id, issue.status.name, issue.tracker.name, issue.tracker.name));

    self.issues = issuesList;

    i++;
      })
    }
    this._issuesService.fetchIssues(callback);
  }
```

Comment: Problem fixed. Thanks

Comment: Great! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh radlistview nativescript on updating data
radlistview refresh
`<RadListView #myListView></RadListView>`

`@ViewChild("myListView") listViewComponent: RadListViewComponent;`
 
//use this whenever you update data in **dataItems**
`this.listViewComponent.listView.refresh();`